# How can I establish to validate at least one input field in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="field_1"    id="field_1"/> Field 1  </label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="field_2"    id="field_2"/> Field 2  </label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_3" value="field_3"    id="field_3"/> Field 3  </label>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="getFormData('action')">   Execute <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> </button>
```

I need a function JS to execute onclick "Execute" which control that at least 1 field is checked before getFormData('action')

Comment: `if ($('input [type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) { ... // do this }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery something like this should work.

```
if($('#field_1').is(':checked') || $('#field_2').is(':checked') || $('#field_3').is(':checked')) {
    // Do something
} else {
    return;
}
```

Or with plain JavaScript

```
let field1 = document.getElementById("field_1").checked;
let field2 = document.getElementById("field_2").checked;
let field3 = document.getElementById("field_3").checked;

if(field1 || field2 || field3) {
    // Do something
} else {
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getFormData(action){
var oneChecked=false;
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        oneChecked=true;
      }
  });
  if(oneChecked){
    console.log("At least one checked");
  }
  else{
    console.log("No one checked");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="field_1"    id="field_1"/> Field 1  </label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="field_2"    id="field_2"/> Field 2  </label>

<label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_3" value="field_3"    id="field_3"/> Field 3  </label>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="getFormData('action')">   Execute <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()` and an array to contain the sate of your inputs. Then expand your function that gets fired on submit to check if the array of states contains any truthy value. If yes, submit.

```js
function getFormData(action, event) {
  var checked = [];
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"');

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checked.push(checkboxes[i].checked);
  }

  if (!checked.includes(true)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="field_1"    id="field_1"/> Field 1  </label>

  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_2" value="field_2"    id="field_2"/> Field 2  </label>

  <label class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_3" value="field_3"    id="field_3"/> Field 3  </label>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="getFormData('action', event)">   Execute <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i> </button>
</form>
```